# "it proved advantageious" -- Is "X proves ADJ" an acceptable usage?

Tags: complementation

> One consequence of the agrarian agitations was the increased use of machinery and the reduction in the number of hands employed, which if it proved advantageous to the landlord and to the few laborers retained, who received higher wages, resulted in an increase of unemployment.

<sup>Source: [The Encyclopaedia Britannica : a dictionary of arts, sciences, literature and general information, Volume XV, 11th ed. (1911)](https://archive.org/stream/encyclopaediabri15chisrich#page/80/mode/1up), page 80.</sup>

Comment: Yes. The law states that you are innocent until proved guilty. This is the third year of the book scheme and it has proved very successful as it greatly reduces the financial burden on parents. If the scheme proves successful the police hope to run surgeries at the town's other secondary schools

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ***prove*** can be used this way. The Macmillan Dictionary classifies it as a linking verb in this usage.

> **[prove](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/prove)**
>   2. [linking verb] if something proves to have a particular quality, things happen that show it has that quality
>   *My decision proved to be a good one.*
>   *The movie is proving very profitable.*
>   *His injuries proved fatal* (=he died because of them).